# Sql Server 2008 coalesce

Tags: sql-server-2008

The following sql returns correct data formatted just as needed, except when no data is returned.

Desired result -- using the coalesce on ename--
 is to return 'none' when no data is returned.

What is it I am doing wrong on the coalesce? Why does it not return 'none' when no data is returned?

When no data is returned, we get all the column names and all are null.

all pointers and suggestions appreciated.

```
select   
        ltrim(right(convert(varchar(20), tstart, 100), 7)) 
        as 'START TIME',
        ltrim(right(convert(varchar(20),   tend, 100), 7)) 
        as 'END TIME',
    coalesce(vb.tname, 'none') as TITLE,
        tr.description as LOCATION
from vwbooks vb
join troom tr
   on vb.room = tr.id
where vb.room in(select id
                     from tblroom 
                    where building = 4971 
   and vb.tstart >=   floor(cast(getdate() as float))
   and vb.tstart <  ceiling(cast(getdate() as float))
   and datepart(hour, vb.tstart) between 6 and 18
```

Comment: Maybe `vb.tname` is never null when you get data? Maybe you meant to do a `left join` instead to get all data from vwbooks even when there is no matching data in troom? Without seeing some sample input data along with actual and expected results it's hard to say what might be wrong.

Comment: @jpw is right, you are returning 0 rows. You are interpreting these as null. You need to understand why nothing is returned. P,  the coalesce will work when it gets a row!

Comment: Spot on.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning 0 rows. You are interpreting these as null. You need to understand why nothing is returned. The coalesce will work when it gets a row!